# How to change default table view frame of Search display controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to change Search display controller table view for showing search result in place of default table view frame of Search display controller.

here is what i was doing :-

```
UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
tblSearchFrame = CGRectMake(0, 135, 320, 180);
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView.frame = tblSearchFrame;
```

i was assigning search display controller table view with my custom table view frame. But this doesn't worked for me.
So i tried to do it by following way :-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView==self.searchController.searchResultsTableView)
{ tableView.frame = tblSearchFrame; }
}
```

this worked but my whole view got displaced and table view was not displaying any data.
Is there any other way to do this thing without displacing view?
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: add the search bar in tableview header

Comment: i tried to did it and it gets scrolled with table view but i want search bar to be fixed.

Comment: then remove the  UISearchDisplayController and add the search bar only

Comment: have a happy day friend

Comment: Bro one more query in search bar when i try to get textfield within search bar sometimes it gets and sometime it doesn't find any textfield.
i tried it like this :- 
for (UIView* subView in searchBarView.subviews) {
for (UIView* searchView in subView.subviews){
for (UIView *text in searchView.subviews){
if ([text isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
foundSearchTextField = (UITextField*)text;
NSLog(@"found");
break;
}
else{
foundSearchTextField = [self.searchBaar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
}}}} @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: code added in comment

Comment: in before u were used the search bar in IOS or this is the first time to use bro

Comment: i have used search bar before but in ios 6, now in ios 7 and from above code some times i get textfield and sometimes it returns nil and don't find any search field @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: don't mine bro i have a emergency wk , plz try this it will be hope for u https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2yaZXn4MU0